# Is there a simple way to quickly disable extensions in Chrome while using the developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

LastPass, Evernote, things like Google Tag Assistant – they all add network requests and asset downloads to page loads. When we're using the developer tools, this makes the experience quite messy. I dislike having to disable and enable extensions one-by-one while I'm working. Is there a better or simpler way to manage what extensions are running? Or a way to disable extensions when the developer tools are open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a separate Chrome profile for your development. See [How to create and manage multiple user profiles in Chrome](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2089364/how-to-create-and-manage-multiple-user-profiles-in-chrome.html) for some instructions on this. You have a completely separate workspace, which means no extensions or accounts are shared between them.

Comment: Wow, I've always thought that switching "People" was for the entire current non-incognito session. This is great – exactly what I needed. I feel silly for not using this sooner.